# Change the table data-priority dynamically in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is that possible to change the `data-priority` dynamically in jquery mobile. That is change the data-priority order depend upon user choice.

```
<table id="tab" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive">
        <thead id="th">
            <tr id="tr1">
                <th>First</th>
                <th data-priority="1">Second</th>
                <th data-priority="2">third</th>
                <th data-priority="3">Fourth</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

</table>
```

in above table `user1` need to `remove the data-priority for third row.` 
`User2` want to `remove the data-priority for fourth  row`. Is that possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easily built in to the jQM table, but with some coding it can be done.

Given this default table head:

```
<thead id="th">
    <tr id="tr1">
        <th>First</th>
        <th data-priority="1" id="col2th">Second</th>
        <th data-priority="2" id="col3th">third</th>
        <th data-priority="3" id="col4th">Fourth</th>
    </tr>            
</thead>
```

jQM uses the data-priority to add classes like ui-table-priority-1, ui-table-priority-2, etc. to the THs in the head and the TDs in the body. So you can use script to remove the data-priority attribute and the classes, then tell the table widget to rebuild

```
$("#btnUser1").on("click", function(e){
    // remove priority on col3
    ResetToDefaultPriorities();
    $("#col3th").removeAttr("data-priority").removeClass();
    $('#tab tbody td').removeClass();
    $('#tab').table( "rebuild" );   
});   

function ResetToDefaultPriorities(){
    $("#col2th").attr("data-priority", '1');
    $("#col3th").attr("data-priority", '2');
    $("#col4th").attr("data-priority", '3');
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/10x1xy8o/)**

Comment: Thank you really good one..If i want to change the data-priority( that is already assingned 5 need to change 1) is not able to change that ..see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/10x1xy8o/3/

Comment: i tried this also `$("#col5th").addClass("ui-table-cell-hidden");` but the class is not added to that field..

Comment: @Anu, you need to remove the priority class as well as changing the data-priority attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/10x1xy8o/4/